# How to create 303 Response in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-status-code-303

Does anyone know how to redirect current request in ASP.NET **using http status code 303** (SeeOther).

Code snippets are more than welcome!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should be able to do it like this:

```
  HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
  HttpContext.Current.Response.Status = "303 See Other";
  HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Location", newLocation);
  HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Answer (score 9):

This is a **.NetCore / .Net5.0+** implementation as an **extension method**.

```
public static class ControllerExtensions
{
    public static ActionResult SeeOther(this Controller controller, string location)
    {
        controller.Response.Headers.Add("Location", location);
        return new StatusCodeResult(303);
    }
}
```

**Usage From Controller:** `return this.SeeOther("/resource-endpoint");`

Comment: HTTP 303 is for "See Other", not for "Exists". There is no HTTP status code named "Exists".

Comment: Consider using `this ControllerBase` instead, and `Uri location` for strong-typing, and to signal intent (a `Uri` object can be used to represent a relative URI, not just absolute URIs)

Comment: I admit my second comment was nit-picking, certainly - but my first comment is serious. HTTP 303 is well-defined as “See Other” (read the spec!). The semantics of HTTP 303 do not say nor suggest the `Location:` destination “exists” (e.g. it’s valid for a 303 redirect to result in a 404). I’m asserting that you are flat-out incorrect by naming your method `Exists` instead of `SeeOther`.